# Sequence in java

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHROu.png)I am trying to write down a code in java that gives every line in my output file a  sequence depending on the changes on a string in the same line for exampl :

```
line1 = xx1x1xxxx
line2 = xx1x2xxxx
line3 = xx1x3xxxx
line1 = xx2x1xxxx
line2 = xx2x2xxxx
line3 = xx2x3xxxx
```

this is my code but it doesn't work :

```
        String seq_flot;
        String seq_flot_old ;
        int compteur = 0;

        if(action.equals("RP")){

            seq_flot = line.substring(42,47);
            seq_flot_old = line.substring(42,47);
            if (seq_flot != seq_flot_old){
                compteur=1;
                line = line.replace("\\", compteur);
                compteur = compteur+1;
                seq_flot_old = seq_flot;
            }
            else if (seq_flot == seq_flot_old) {
                line = line.replace("\\", compteur);
                compteur = compteur+1;
                seq_flot_old = seq_flot;
            }

            }
```

Comment: Time to (learn to) use a debugger then.

Comment: String comparison using == or != is a bad idea. Use the .equals() method instead

Comment: i am working on a server not  on local !

Comment: Isolate the code and use a debugger!

Comment: @AnasRafei : Could you please tell us what's the problem ? Isn't this code compiling ? Isn't it running ? Isn't it giving you the right results ? If yes, where's the mistake ?

Comment: how can i do it with the equals methode ?

Comment: in fact this is the error that i get  The method replace(char, char) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)

Comment: i have in the output a text file with lines i need to give them a number that increment for each line and go to 1 again oif the seq_flot_old changes

Comment: Yes because replace is a method that replace a char (or String) by another char (or String) in your original String.

Comment: so this way is not working :(

Comment: i have added  a image in the post in the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restart from scratch : 
What I understand your question should have been :

I have a sequence of Strings and want to check the difference between them. Whenever a line is the same as the previous one, i want to increment a counter (that counted the occurence of that line). Whenever a new line appears, i want to increment another counter and reset the first one to 1.
I don't expect the line be equal to a several times older one.
I want the response in the form of the following String : #numberOfTimesTheLineChanged(on 5 digits)#numberOfTimeTheLineAppeared#

For example :
When inputed

```
aaa
aaa
aab
aab
aab
bab
```

I expect :

```
#00001#1#
#00001#2#
#00002#1#
#00002#2#
#00002#3#
#00003#1#
```

My code is :

> Blabla.

And I would then have answered you :

You can try :

```
public static List<String> INPUT = Arrays.asList("aaa","aaa","aab","aab","aab","bab");  // my input data
public static List<String> OUTPUT = Arrays.asList("#00001#1#","#00001#2#","#00002#1#","#00002#2#","#00002#3#","#00003#1#"); //my expected response

public static String RESPONSE_FORMAT = "#%05d#%01d#"; //formatting the response into a String;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    int counterOccurence = 0;
    int counterChanges = 0;
    String lastLine = "";
    for(String line : INPUT){
        if(lastLine.equals(line)){
            counterOccurence++;
        } else {
            counterOccurence= 1;
            counterChanges++;
        }
        output.add(String.format(RESPONSE_FORMAT, counterChanges,counterOccurence));
        lastLine = line; //remember last line
    }
    System.out.println(output);
    System.out.println("It matches : "+output.equals(OUTPUT));
```

It returns me with :

> [#00001#1#, #00001#2#, #00002#1#, #00002#2#, #00002#3#, #00003#1#]
>   It matches : true

Does that answer your question ?

Comment: Well, the response format only prints a single digit for the second counter, so if you expect more than 9 occurrences of the same line in a row, you should change the format to `"#%05d#%d#`. I did my best to match your picture. Sorry for the condescending tone, but we wasted a lot of time by not being able to communicate on what you wanted.

Comment: lol yes it's my fault  i am sorry for that thank you very much jeremy

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if my answer is correct,but Ill try it :

Replace :

```
line = line.replace("\\", compteur);
```

With :

```
line = line.replace(new String("\\").charAt(0), Integer.toString(compteur).charAt(0));
```

This is because String.replace is for replacing characters in the string with other characters, and in java you'll have to make sure you're always using the right datatype the function can use.

EDIT : And as @Jeremy Grand pointed out, your string comparison is wrong, too. `(seq_flot == seq_flot_old)` has to be `(seq_float.equals(seq_float_old)` and `(seq_float != seq_float_old)` has to be `(seq_float.equals(seq_float_old)==false)`

Hope it helps you !

Comment: using String::new is a bad practice, prefer using `line = line.replace("\\",Integer.toString(compteur));` (Replace also works with Strings, just not with int)

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply but i have this error now : 'The method getAt(int) is undefined for the type String'

Comment: @Anas Rafei Im very sorry, it has to be charAt

Comment: @JeremyGrand : I think it doesnt work with ints, only with chars or (probably) Strings

Comment: @user7185318, that what i was saying. You should use String.replace(String,String) rather than that awful new String.charAt. Well, see my answer. It fixes a bit OP's code.

Comment: i have added an image in the first of my post

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code, but I assume it's just because you modified it before posting.
However, regarding the part you asked about, you should replace

```
if (seq_flot != seq_flot_old){
            compteur=1;
            line = line.replace("\\", compteur);
            compteur = compteur+1;
            seq_flot_old = seq_flot;
        }
        else if (seq_flot == seq_flot_old) {
            line = line.replace("\\", compteur);
            compteur = compteur+1;
            seq_flot_old = seq_flot;
        }
```

by

```
if (seq_flot.equals(seq_flot_old)){
        compteur=1; //resets compteur
    } else {
        compteur++; 
    }
seq_flot_old = seq_flot;
line = line.replace("\\", Integer.toString(compteur));
```

EDIT : trying to take the time to help you. I have to admit that your code does not make sense to me at all. There's duplication, useless checks and I can't figure out what you were trying to do.

However, by reading your question, I assume you meant something close to that (where I removed the action.equals("RP") part because it had no influence on the rest of the code) :

```
String seq_old_flot = file.readLine().substring(42,47); // substring of first line of file
String line = file.readLine(); // second line of file
int compteur =0;
while(line != null){ //end condition
    String seq_flot = line.substring(42, 47); //the interesting part of the line
    if(seq_flot.equals(seq_old_flot)){ //no changes between old and new sequence
        compteur = 1; //resets the compteur to 1
    } else {
        compteur++; //increments compteur
    }
    writeToLogFile(seq_flot.replace("\\", Integer.toString(compteur))); // replace the \ by your compteur
    seq_old_flot = seq_flot; //remember sequence 
    line = file.readLine(); // read next line
}
```

Comment: there two string comparisons, you only fixed one :)

Comment: No the whole two comparisons made no sense to me. The second if is necessarily true if the first one was false. That's why I said there were issues with OP's code.

Comment: @JeremyGrand it increments when the substring changes it is a sequence

Comment: @AnasRafei true, I had swapped the conditions. However, please look at the second part, it makes much more sense in my opinion.

Comment: i have tried it but in the place of the sequence i have 11 every where is that normal ?

Comment: I don't know what your line looked like at first, so the \ was maybe replaced several times. However, your original code modified the line, thus resulting in the line changing everytime.

Comment: @JeremyGrand i have added a picture in the first of my poste

Comment: Ah i guess the part that you wanted to replace was an actual `\\ `. Please understand that in a java string `"\\"` actually means `\ ` ; use `"\\\\"` to reprensent two backslashes. And after that, your expected result show the need to use TWO counters, your sample code never showed any hint of it. You need to work on your conceptualization of your problem and your explanation to others.

Comment: i am sorry if i was not clear in my questions  i think that i need to replace the "\"  by "*"

Comment: You haven't clearly exposed your question. What I guessed you need is comparing n lines while keeping two counters : one for the number of time the line you're comparing changed and one for the number of time every different line was found the same. You were way off to explain it. You always talked about what you expected but never what were your inputs nor what you wanted to do with them. Your code made no sense at all and I needed around ten comments from you to understand you simply needed a group by method. Which can be done in a two-liner.